# Why does the  (delta) term exist in the density-density correlation for simple liquids?

Tags: statistical-thermodynamics, from-phys-se, derivations

[Cross-posted from the PhysicsSE.](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/746687/why-does-the-delta-term-exist-in-the-density-density-correlation-for-simple-l)

I am reading *Theory of Simple Liquids* by Hansen and McDonald, and they in chapter 3, they describe the density-density correlation for a simple liquid in the grand canonical ensemble. This is how they have defined it:
$$H^{(2)}(r,r') = \langle [\rho (r) - \langle \rho (r) \rangle ][ \rho (r') - \langle \rho (r') \rangle ]\rangle \tag{1}$$
$$ = \rho ^{(2)}(r,r') - \rho ^{(1)}(r)\rho ^{(1)}(r') + \rho ^{(1)}(r) \delta (r-r').\tag{2}$$
This is my understanding of where the terms in the RHS comes from. I understand that the two-particle density $\rho^{(2)}$ term arises from:
$$\langle \rho (r) \rho (r') \rangle\tag{3}$$
in the RHS.

The second term in the RHS comes from expanding the the product and taking like terms together.

$$-\rho ^{(1)}(r)\rho ^{(1)}(r') = -\langle \rho(r) \langle \rho (r') \rangle \rangle - \langle \rho(r') \langle \rho (r) \rangle \rangle + \rho ^{(1)}(r) \rho ^{(1)}(r'),\tag{4}$$
where $\rho^{(1)}(r)$ is the average single-particle density at $r$, for a homogeneous liquid.

But I still do not get why that $\delta$-function exists there. Is the $\delta$-function just there to say that if the two particles are in the same spot ($r=r'$), the density correlation is... maximized? How does the $\delta$ fall out of the averaging, mathematically?

I would appreciate any advice you have for me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While deriving this formula in Ch. 3 of your source, the author references equation 2.5.13,
\begin{equation}
\rho_N^{(2)}\left(\mathbf{r}, \mathbf{r}^{\prime}\right)=\left\langle\sum_{i=1}^N \sum_{j=1}^N{}^{'} \delta\left(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}_i\right) \delta\left(\mathbf{r}^{\prime}-\mathbf{r}_j\right)\right\rangle.\tag{2.5.13}
\end{equation}
The author calls $\rho^{(2)}\left(\mathbf{r},\mathbf{r}'\right)$ an analogue of the above.

Notice the second sum has a prime indicating it is missing a set of terms where $i = j$. Those missing terms are

\begin{equation}
\left\langle\sum_{i=1}^{N}\delta\left(\mathbf{r} - \mathbf{r}_{i}\right)\delta\left(\mathbf{r}' - \mathbf{r}_{i}\right)\right\rangle = \left\langle\sum_{i=1}^{N}\delta\left(\mathbf{r} - \mathbf{r}_{i}\right)\right\rangle\delta\left(\mathbf{r} - \mathbf{r}'\right) =\rho^{(1)}\left(\mathbf{r} \right)\delta\left(\mathbf{r} - \mathbf{r}'\right),
\end{equation}
where the final equality comes from Eq. (3.1.2) in the source. Anytime $\mathbf{r} \neq \mathbf{r}'$, the whole thing vanishes due to the two coupled $\delta$-functions.

Comment: +1. Just to be clear: the equation that you labeled 2.5.13 in your answer is also 2.5.13 in the book? I'm a bit confused because your sentence seems to suggest that 2.5.13 in the book is an "analogue" of your 2.5.13.

Comment: I edited the comment for clarity.

Comment: This is great! Thank you for spelling it out!

Comment: I am trying to write in words what the second equation you have written means. Put simply, $\rho (r,r')$ is a measure of how likely it is for two ```identical``` particles to be at $r$ and $r'$, averaging (integrating) out the positions of other particles. What I am struggling to see is how I can go from the left-most term in the second equation, to the one in the middle. Why does the $\delta (r-r')$ term come OUTSIDE the ensemble averaging brackets? $\langle \rangle$?

Comment: To begin with, in the second $\delta$ function, you can clearly switch out $\mathbf{r}_{i}$ for $\mathbf{r}$ without affecting the overall sum, as $\mathbf{r} = \mathbf{r}' = \mathbf{r}_{i}$ or the term drops out. So then you must think about whether averaging over the sum of products of $\delta$ functions is any different than averaging over the sum of one and multiplying by the other.

In either case if $\mathbf{r} \neq \mathbf{r}'$, the entire average drops to zero. Only if $\mathbf{r} = \mathbf{r}'$ does the average become finite, and both options will simply multiply all terms by 1.